# Changing a Child theme's name on MAMP localhost

Tags: child-theme, phpmyadmin

I would like to change the child-theme name on my localhost (MAMP) set up for a project I'm working on. Obviously changing the folder name is easy enough, as is changing the child-theme's name in the comments at the top of the child-theme's style.css file.

How do I change the info in the database / phpMyAdmin though? Which I'm guessing I'll have to do because of how the child-theme links to the database?

Any help would be amazing.

Emily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Recommended Method

You don't have to change anything in the database. Follow these steps:

1. Activate a default WordPress theme (e.g. `twentyseventeen`) - that is any theme other than the child theme you are going to rename.
2. Rename your child Themes folder name and child theme's name in `style.css` file.
3. Now activate the child theme.

That's all, WordPress will update related info. in the Database autometically.

> Note: You've already figured out step-2 correctly. Just need to follow step-1 before step-2 and then step-3 afterwards. That's all.

## Database Method:

It's also possible to change the theme name from the database after following step-2 above. Sometimes it's helpful in case you've already changed the theme name & now can't access the site because WordPress has a different theme name in the Database.

In this case, know that WordPress saves two values in the `wp_options` table. One is with the `option_name` = `stylesheet` and the other one is the `option_name` = `template`.

If it's not a child theme, then both the values are same. For a child theme however, `option_name` = `stylesheet` will have `option_value` = `your-current-child-theme-name` and `option_name` = `template` will have `option_value` = `parent-theme-name`.

So if you change these two values accordingly, it'll work as well. You can use PHPMyAdmin, or the following MySQL query:

```
update wp_options set option_value = 'new-child-theme-name' where option_name = 'stylesheet';

update wp_options set option_value = 'parent-theme-name' where option_name = 'template';
```

> replace `new-child-theme-name` and `parent-theme-name` accordingly in the above query.

Comment: and if you're curious in learning more about how WP stores things "under the hood", the child theme name is stored as the value of the `option_value` column of the `$wpdb->options` row whose `option_name == 'stylsheet'`

Comment: Thanks for that Fayaz.  I couldn't find the answer anywhere on the site.

Comment: @EmilyChewy that's OK, we all were there at some point.